# Can we change the lock after thread enter synchronized block?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am asking this question is just for curiosity, I know it is stupid to do such thing.

```
public void doSomething() 
{
      synchronized(object_A){
        count++;
        average = count/total;
      }
}
```

Now let say I have 2 thread run concurrently (calling function doSomething()), while the first thread already enter the block, let say at the line "count++", the second thread is blocked and waiting the lock.

Now I try to do `object_A = new LockObject()` (in another thread). Now what happen to thread 1 and thread 2?

Will thread 2 enter the block? Since it already executed statement "synchronized(object_A)", is it too late to change the lock?

Will thread 1 change the lock while in the sync block (assume thread 1 still in the block)?

Comment: Thread 1 will not change the lock. It holds the lock on the object that is referenced by variable object_A; once it gets the lock, it forgets about the variable. You can even `synchronized(someMethod()) {}`

Comment: About thread 2, I guess (but I may be wrong) that it will still compete for the first lock. [JLS 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.19) says that 1. the expression is evaluated, and after that 2. the thread acquires the lock, but 3. a thread cannot do 2 while another thread is holding the lock. So it looks to me that thread 2 won't re-read the reference from the variable, thus making the variable assignment uneffective.

Comment: Anyway, you should be aware that there's another issue here - a variable assignment may be ineffective if it is not volatile, and no synchronization occurs after the assignment. This is because threads are allowed to make local copies of the variables, and are only required to update those local copies on volatile/synchronized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's like ignis said, but Thread 2 will see the new reference after Thread 1 is done, because it has to refresh all variables.

Comment: This is about my 3rd comment on volatile/synchronized, and I agree that Thread 2 will see the updated variable. But this does not imply that Thread 2 will lock on the new object, see my 2nd comment on the jls.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem would be data integrity. Threads will be synchronizing on different locks and the data protected by the locks will have wrong values. Locks are created in the instance initializer's as private final fields or in the constructor of the class.